# Spring Roo project. Project build error: Failed to execute goal

Tags: java, maven, spring-roo

I create a project based on the code from the [site](https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)

```
roo> project setup --topLevelPackage com.foo
roo> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
roo> entity jpa --class ~.domain.Timer
roo> field string --fieldName message --notNull
roo> repository jpa --all
roo> service --all
roo> web mvc setup
roo> web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
roo> web mvc controller --all --responseType THYMELEAF
roo> web mvc controller --all --pathPrefix /api
roo> quit
mvn spring-boot:run
```

The building of the project is completed with the following error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.054 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-20T19:45:28+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process
default) on project hello: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on
he classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse und
r JDK as well -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swi
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

POM.xml can be found [here](https://github.com/vol2hv/hello/blob/master/pom.xml). Spring roo-2.0.0.RELEASE
The error is also displayed in the pom.xml file (the line 592):

```
You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.
If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under
 JDK as well (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources)
```

In elcipse configuration - c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181.
When I run the project from the command line `mvn spring-boot:run`, I get the same result

Comment: The error is pretty clear.... You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well.... You need to install a JDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the file Sts.ini you need to add to the beginning

```
-vm
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/javaw.exe
```

In the file pom.xml replace `<aspectj.plugin.version>1.8</aspectj.plugin.version>` on `<aspectj.plugin.version>1.9</aspectj.plugin.version>`

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

It's unfortunately an Eclipse issue - because you're pointing Eclipse to the JDK - which is good, but Eclipse itself is a Java app that also runs in a JVM. And it's running in the JRE instead of the JDK.
The way to fix that is - in your `eclipse.ini` (or `STS.ini` - if you're using Eclipse STS) - you add this first line:

```
-vm 
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javaw.exe
```

- make sure you put the right path and then put these lines just above `-vmargs` according to [Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

---

**Second:**

Also make sure you are having the jre as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install JDK
if you already have JDK, check your elcipse configuration on window>preferences>java>Installed JREs
and point your JDK path like this C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

Comment: In elcipse configuration - c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181.